# Conceptual understanding of PHP server session

Tags: php, webserver

So as a engineer, I usually require a concert understanding to be able to work with something. I feel like I understand the basics of a session. I am wondering about the specifics and details there of.

What are the limitations of a session?

How can I manipulate a session? What can explicitly not be done to or with a session.

What data structures does PHP use to define and manage sessions?

Is a PHP session different from any other session in any significant way?

I understand that these questions are general, so if anyone can simply suggest a good resource I would be thankful. There is plenty of info out there, but it is either too basic or teaching to a specific topic.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You should look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Yup, this is what I need. I'll have to pour through this. Thank you.

Comment: __There is plenty of info out there, but it is either too basic or teaching to a specific topic.__ the answers to your question are all there in those infos because what you have asked here is basics.

Comment: Is there perhaps a better place for general questions of this nature? I had not realized that the php site would have the answer I seek. @Baba gave the answer I was looking for. Is there maybe a tag for general questions, a separate stack perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions is a way for the server to **recognize you** so he sends to you a customized version of the page instead of sending always the same page for everybody.

To recognize you one way is he tells the browser to save in your computer a small file with a simple text, and when you visit the page again the server would ask the browser for that file, if the browser sends it, and it contains the expected content, the server can now know this is you again. That are **cookies**.

Another way to maintain a session, a part from cookies, is the server puts a special unique token for you in the url of all the links the page has. Whenever you browse the site all pages you visit will have that token, the server see it and know it's the token it made to you, so he knows it's you again.

So both with **cookies** or **url-based** sessions, the server will have to save info about the sessions opened, for example to store the `$_SESSION` variables you create in **PHP**, if you create such a variable the server will save it to a file which he will later identified by your cookie or token content and when you re-visit the page he will read that file and load the `$_SESSION` variables you create last time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good resource: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

- What are the limitations of a session?

I don't really know what you mean by that.  Limitations in what context?

- How can I manipulate a session?

To manipulate values, just use the `$_SESSION` superglobal directly.

- What can explicitly not be done to or with a session?

Again, without context, it's hard to understand what you mean.  I guess an important point is that sessions are transient, so you can't explicitly store data you want to keep indefinitely.

- What data structures does PHP use to define and manage sessions?

The filesystem.

- Is a PHP session different from any other session in any significant way?

What is another session?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net is the best source for your questions

Answer (score 1):

PHP session is a very nice way of having persistent information on your site for different users.

Check out the [PHP session functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) you can use.

You can [view examples of how to use sessions at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).

A session is most commonly associated with user accounts. A user can log into your site, and you create a user session to keep track of their information and make sure they are allowed to be logged in.

The basic assumption is that a session is **secure**, because the server is aware of the sessions in progress. Utilizing sessions over HTTPS is a fairly secure way of keeping users logged into your site (without HTTPS you run the risk of [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)).

The other basic function is to have persistent data about a given user. So let's say you wanted to keep track if the user has submitted a form, you could do:

```
$_SESSION['form_submitted'] = TRUE;
```

And now you can check that global variable whenever you want to know if that specific user has submitted the form. So the session (in the same way a cookie is used) allows you to do really cool things that otherwise would not be possible.